# How to Echo Post + $list in new line?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will "echo" name + name2 + surname from post e.g

```
John "Edward" "Smith"
Thomas "Edward" "Smith"
Chris "Edward" "Smith"
etc.
```

This is my script:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Test: <input type="text" name="name2"> + <input type="text" name="surname"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

list of names:

```
<?php
$name= "
John
Thomas
Chris
(...)
    ";
?>
```

+

```
<?php echo $name; ?> "<?php echo $_POST["name2"]; ?>" "<?php echo $_POST["surname"]; ?>"
```

When I press Submit I got this

```
John Thomas Chris + "Edward" "Smith"
```

instead of

```
John "Edward" "Smith"
Thomas "Edward" "Smith"
Chris "Edward" "Smith"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `$name` an array. Try this:

```
$names = array(
    "John",
    "Thomas",
    "Chris"
);

foreach($names as $name)
{
    // Added variables for readability
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    echo "$name '$name2' '$surname'";
}

/* OUTPUT:
John 'Edward' 'Smith'
Thomas 'Edward' 'Smith'
Chris 'Edward' 'Smith'
*/
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work with arrays. $name should be an array which you will have to loop through and add the fields from your $_POST form.